# Dual booting Windows 10 and Scientific Linux 7

Tags: dual-boot, scientific-linux

I've installed many versions of ubuntu along side windwos 7, 8 and 10, but a friend wanted me to install scientific linux 7 along side her Windows 10 on her laptop.

Two questions:

1) Does Scientific Linux have an easy dual boot installer like Ubuntu does?
2) Any problems specific with Scientific Linux I might run into?

Comment: I have not used Scientific Linux, but it looks like the installer is [Anaconda](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Distros), which is used on Fedora as well.  My own experience was that the Anaconda interface was less intuitive that the one used by Ubuntu.  It works fine, but it made me nervous the first couple of times I used it to set up a dual boot.

Comment: Setting up the drive partitions tends to be the tricky part.  If you're worried about accidentally formatting the wrong partitions, you could consider using a gparted live cd to set up the drive partitions *before* booting the Scientific Linux installer. That's just an idea and not at all necessary, since I found Anaconda perfectly usable once I got more familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps leave some free partition space before installing SL7 (and make sure you make GRUB2 the bootloader during the install)? But test this in a VM first, so you don't screw up the computer. Also see [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/214571/how-to-dual-boot-linux-on-your-pc/) webpage.